# How to manipulate a variable name in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable name in Bash as:

```
var=(any_word)_SuSE_11_design_guides
```

I want to manipulate the name such that I can have:

```
x=$(echo "$var" | some operation)
echo $x
SuSE_11_design_guides
```

Basically I want to remove every character behind first `_` when detected. How to achieve this?

Comment: what you're saying makes NO sense, if you are "removing" everything behind first _ then `echo $x` would have whatever's (any_word) and NOT SuSE_11_design_guides. Because if you wanted that then you'd simply set `x=SuSE_11_design_guides` and you're done.  Instead do you mean that you trying to get (any_word) in `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant retain *Everything behind first* _ , which can be achieved using parameter-expansion.

```
string="(anyword)_SuSE_11_design_guides"
printf "%s\n" "${string#*_}"
SuSE_11_design_guides
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear whether you want to print SuSE_11_design_guides, or whatever came before. So, I'll answer both.

```
# Print the content before the first `_`
echo $var | awk -F_ '{ print $1 }'
```

If you want to print the trailing part:

```
echo $var | sed -E 's/.*(SuSE_11_design_guides).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ var=(any_word)_SuSE_11_design_guides
$ echo ${var##${var%%SuSE_11_design_guides}}
SuSE_11_design_guides
```

The above echo statement is comprised of two nested bash strings function.
Breaking down what this does, it is the equivalent of:

```
let a=${var%%SuSE_11_design_guides}
```

The above line strips "SuSE_11_design_guides" off the tail of `$var` returning the prefix

```
${var##$a}
```

The above strips whatever is in `$a` (which happens to be the prefix as per the previous step), from the beginning of `$var`, leaving the suffix.

I combined them in the original example just because I could. It definitely makes it harder to read, but I was going for shock value :-)